# Fails Hibernate JSON mapping to PostgreSQL database in Spring Boot web application

Tags: java, json, hibernate, postgresql, spring-boot

everybody!!! I'm developing a Spring Boot web application with PostgreSQL database connection. I need to make Hibernate mapping between the MyJson field in UserData Entity and jsonb-type field in the corresponding PG table column. But when I run my application, I see the following Errors

```html
2016-06-26 14:16:39.504  INFO 4552 --- [on(2)-127.0.0.1] alex.pol.Application                     : Starting Application v0.0.1-SNAPSHOT on Dmitriy-Litvinenko with PID 4552 (/home/dima/Web/apache-tomcat-8.0.32/webapps/ROOT/WEB-INF/classes started by dima in /home/dima/Web/apache-tomcat-8.0.32/bin)
2016-06-26 14:16:39.549  INFO 4552 --- [on(2)-127.0.0.1] alex.pol.Application                     : No active profile set, falling back to default profiles: default
2016-06-26 14:16:40.829  INFO 4552 --- [on(2)-127.0.0.1] ationConfigEmbeddedWebApplicationContext : Refreshing org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.AnnotationConfigEmbeddedWebApplicationContext@7a3995da: startup date [Sun Jun 26 14:16:40 EEST 2016]; root of context hierarchy
2016-06-26 14:16:43.153  INFO 4552 --- [on(2)-127.0.0.1] o.s.b.f.s.DefaultListableBeanFactory     : Overriding bean definition for bean 'beanNameViewResolver' with a different definition: replacing [Root bean: class [null]; scope=; abstract=false; lazyInit=false; autowireMode=3; dependencyCheck=0; autowireCandidate=true; primary=false; factoryBeanName=org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.web.ErrorMvcAutoConfiguration$WhitelabelErrorViewConfiguration; factoryMethodName=beanNameViewResolver; initMethodName=null; destroyMethodName=(inferred); defined in class path resource [org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/web/ErrorMvcAutoConfiguration$WhitelabelErrorViewConfiguration.class]] with [Root bean: class [null]; scope=; abstract=false; lazyInit=false; autowireMode=3; dependencyCheck=0; autowireCandidate=true; primary=false; factoryBeanName=org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.web.WebMvcAutoConfiguration$WebMvcAutoConfigurationAdapter; factoryMethodName=beanNameViewResolver; initMethodName=null; destroyMethodName=(inferred); defined in class path resource [org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/web/WebMvcAutoConfiguration$WebMvcAutoConfigurationAdapter.class]]
2016-06-26 14:16:44.144  INFO 4552 --- [on(2)-127.0.0.1] f.a.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor : JSR-330 'javax.inject.Inject' annotation found and supported for autowiring
2016-06-26 14:16:44.342  INFO 4552 --- [on(2)-127.0.0.1] trationDelegate$BeanPostProcessorChecker : Bean 'org.springframework.transaction.annotation.ProxyTransactionManagementConfiguration' of type [class org.springframework.transaction.annotation.ProxyTransactionManagementConfiguration$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$8ad0af19] is not eligible for getting processed by all BeanPostProcessors (for example: not eligible for auto-proxying)
2016-06-26 14:16:44.517  INFO 4552 --- [on(2)-127.0.0.1] o.s.web.context.ContextLoader            : Root WebApplicationContext: initialization completed in 3689 ms
2016-06-26 14:16:45.940  INFO 4552 --- [on(2)-127.0.0.1] b.a.w.TomcatWebSocketContainerCustomizer : NonEmbeddedServletContainerFactory detected. Websockets support should be native so this normally is not a problem.
2016-06-26 14:16:46.818  INFO 4552 --- [on(2)-127.0.0.1] o.s.b.c.e.ServletRegistrationBean        : Mapping servlet: 'dispatcherServlet' to [/]
2016-06-26 14:16:46.837  INFO 4552 --- [on(2)-127.0.0.1] o.s.b.c.embedded.FilterRegistrationBean  : Mapping filter: 'errorPageFilter' to: [/*]
2016-06-26 14:16:46.838  INFO 4552 --- [on(2)-127.0.0.1] o.s.b.c.embedded.FilterRegistrationBean  : Mapping filter: 'characterEncodingFilter' to: [/*]
2016-06-26 14:16:46.838  INFO 4552 --- [on(2)-127.0.0.1] o.s.b.c.embedded.FilterRegistrationBean  : Mapping filter: 'hiddenHttpMethodFilter' to: [/*]
2016-06-26 14:16:46.838  INFO 4552 --- [on(2)-127.0.0.1] o.s.b.c.embedded.FilterRegistrationBean  : Mapping filter: 'httpPutFormContentFilter' to: [/*]
2016-06-26 14:16:46.838  INFO 4552 --- [on(2)-127.0.0.1] o.s.b.c.embedded.FilterRegistrationBean  : Mapping filter: 'requestContextFilter' to: [/*]
2016-06-26 14:16:49.350  INFO 4552 --- [on(2)-127.0.0.1] j.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean : Building JPA container EntityManagerFactory for persistence unit 'default'
2016-06-26 14:16:49.382  WARN 4552 --- [on(2)-127.0.0.1] ationConfigEmbeddedWebApplicationContext : Exception encountered during context initialization - cancelling refresh attempt: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'entityManagerFactory' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/orm/jpa/HibernateJpaAutoConfiguration.class]: Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/hibernate/tool/schema/spi/DelayedDropRegistry
2016-06-26 14:16:49.423 ERROR 4552 --- [on(2)-127.0.0.1] o.s.boot.SpringApplication               : Application startup failed

org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'entityManagerFactory' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/orm/jpa/HibernateJpaAutoConfiguration.class]: Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/hibernate/tool/schema/spi/DelayedDropRegistry
 at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1578) ~[spring-beans-4.2.5.RELEASE.jar:4.2.5.RELEASE]
```

Here is my UserData class file

```html
@Entity(name = "UserData")
@TypeDef(name = "MyJsonType",typeClass = MyJsonType.class)
public class UserData extends BaseModel {

    private String firstName;

    private String secondName;

    @Column
    @Type(type = "MyJsonType")
    private MyJson jsonProperty;/*//socialData;*/

    @OneToOne(cascade = CascadeType.MERGE)
    @JoinColumn(name = "user_id")
    private User user;

    public User getUser() {
        return user;
    }

    public void setUser(User user) {
        this.user = user;
    }

}
```

Here is MyJson.java file

```html
import java.io.Serializable;

public class MyJson implements Serializable {

    private String stringProp;

    private Long longProp;

    public String getStringProp() {
        return stringProp;
    }

    public void setStringProp(String stringProp) {
        this.stringProp = stringProp;
    }

    public Long getLongProp() {
        return longProp;
    }

    public void setLongProp(Long longProp) {
        this.longProp = longProp;
    }
}
```

MyJsonType.java file

```html
import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper;
import org.hibernate.HibernateException;
import org.hibernate.engine.spi.SessionImplementor;
import org.hibernate.usertype.UserType;

import java.io.*;
import java.sql.PreparedStatement;
import java.sql.ResultSet;
import java.sql.SQLException;
import java.sql.Types;

public class MyJsonType implements UserType {

    @Override
    public int[] sqlTypes() {
        return new int[]{Types.JAVA_OBJECT};
    }

    @Override
    public Class<MyJson> returnedClass() {
        return MyJson.class;
    }

    @Override
    public Object nullSafeGet(final ResultSet rs, final String[] names, final SessionImplementor session,
                              final Object owner) throws HibernateException, SQLException {
        final String cellContent = rs.getString(names[0]);
        if (cellContent == null) {
            return null;
        }
        try {
            final ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
            return mapper.readValue(cellContent.getBytes("UTF-8"), returnedClass());
        } catch (final Exception ex) {
            throw new RuntimeException("Failed to convert String to Invoice: " + ex.getMessage(), ex);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void nullSafeSet(final PreparedStatement ps, final Object value, final int idx,
                            final SessionImplementor session) throws HibernateException, SQLException {
        if (value == null) {
            ps.setNull(idx, Types.OTHER);
            return;
        }
        try {
            final ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
            final StringWriter w = new StringWriter();
            mapper.writeValue(w, value);
            w.flush();
            ps.setObject(idx, w.toString(), Types.OTHER);
        } catch (final Exception ex) {
            throw new RuntimeException("Failed to convert Invoice to String: " + ex.getMessage(), ex);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public Object deepCopy(final Object value) throws HibernateException {
        try {
            // use serialization to create a deep copy
            ByteArrayOutputStream bos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
            ObjectOutputStream oos = new ObjectOutputStream(bos);
            oos.writeObject(value);
            oos.flush();
            oos.close();
            bos.close();

            ByteArrayInputStream bais = new ByteArrayInputStream(bos.toByteArray());
            return new ObjectInputStream(bais).readObject();
        } catch (ClassNotFoundException | IOException ex) {
            throw new HibernateException(ex);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public boolean isMutable() {
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public Serializable disassemble(final Object value) throws HibernateException {
        return (Serializable) this.deepCopy(value);
    }

    @Override
    public Object assemble(final Serializable cached, final Object owner) throws HibernateException {
        return this.deepCopy(cached);
    }

    @Override
    public Object replace(final Object original, final Object target, final Object owner) throws HibernateException {
        return this.deepCopy(original);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean equals(final Object obj1, final Object obj2) throws HibernateException {
        if (obj1 == null) {
            return obj2 == null;
        }
        return obj1.equals(obj2);
    }

    @Override
    public int hashCode(final Object obj) throws HibernateException {
        return obj.hashCode();
    }

}
```

MyPostgreSQL94Dialect.java file

```html
import org.hibernate.dialect.PostgreSQL94Dialect;

import java.sql.Types;

public class MyPostgreSQL94Dialect extends PostgreSQL94Dialect {

    public MyPostgreSQL94Dialect() {
        super();
        this.registerColumnType(Types.JAVA_OBJECT, "jsonb");
    }
}
```

And my pom.xml file

```html
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
 xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
 <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

 <groupId>com.example</groupId>
 <artifactId>UBWApp</artifactId>
 <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
 <packaging>war</packaging>

 <name>UBWApp</name>
 <description>UBWApp</description>

 <parent>
  <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
  <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
  <version>1.3.3.RELEASE</version>
  <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
 </parent>

 <properties>
  <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
  <java.version>1.8</java.version>
 </properties>

 <dependencies>
  <dependency>
  <groupId>org.springframework.social</groupId>
   <artifactId>spring-social-github</artifactId>
   <version>1.0.0.BUILD-SNAPSHOT</version>
  </dependency>
  <dependency>
   <groupId>org.apache.httpcomponents</groupId>
   <artifactId>httpclient</artifactId>
   <version>4.5.2</version>
  </dependency>
  <dependency>
  <groupId>org.springframework.social</groupId>
   <artifactId>spring-social-core</artifactId>
   <version>1.1.0.RELEASE</version>
  </dependency>
  <dependency>
     <groupId>org.springframework.social</groupId>
   <artifactId>spring-social-facebook</artifactId>
   <version>2.0.3.RELEASE</version>
  </dependency>
  <dependency>
  <groupId>org.springframework.social</groupId>
   <artifactId>spring-social-linkedin</artifactId>
   <version>1.0.2.RELEASE</version>
  </dependency>
  <dependency>
  <groupId>org.springframework.social</groupId>
   <artifactId>spring-social-google</artifactId>
   <version>1.0.0.RC1</version>
  </dependency>
  <dependency>
  <groupId>org.springframework.social</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-social-twitter</artifactId>
    <version>1.1.0.RELEASE</version>
   </dependency>
  <dependency>
   <groupId>com.github.weekens</groupId>
   <artifactId>spring-social-vkontakte</artifactId>
   <version>1.1.1.RELEASE</version>
  </dependency>
  <dependency>
   <groupId>org.springframework.social</groupId>
   <artifactId>spring-social-web</artifactId>
   <version>1.1.4.RELEASE</version>
  </dependency>
  <dependency>
   <groupId>org.springframework.social</groupId>
   <artifactId>spring-social-config</artifactId>
   <version>1.1.4.RELEASE</version>
  </dependency>
  <dependency>
  <groupId>org.glassfish.jersey.security</groupId>
   <artifactId>oauth1-server</artifactId>
   <version>2.4.1</version>
  </dependency>
  <dependency>
   <groupId>org.apache.commons</groupId>
   <artifactId>commons-lang3</artifactId>
   <version>3.0</version>
  </dependency>
  <dependency>
   <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
   <artifactId>jstl</artifactId>
  </dependency>
  <dependency>
   <groupId>net.sf.json-lib</groupId>
   <artifactId>json-lib</artifactId>
   <version>2.4</version>
   <classifier>jdk15</classifier>
  </dependency>
  <dependency>
   <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
   <artifactId>hibernate-core</artifactId>
   <version>5.0.9.Final</version>
  </dependency>
  <dependency>
   <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
   <artifactId>hibernate-entitymanager</artifactId>
   <version>5.1.0.Final</version>
  </dependency>
  <dependency>
   <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
   <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-tomcat</artifactId>
   <!--<scope>provided</scope>-->
  </dependency>
  <dependency>
   <groupId>javax.servlet.jsp</groupId>
   <artifactId>jsp-api</artifactId>
   <version>2.1</version>
   <scope>provided</scope>
  </dependency>
  <dependency>
   <groupId>jstl</groupId>
   <artifactId>jstl</artifactId>
   <version>1.2</version>
  </dependency>
  <dependency>
   <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
   <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
  </dependency>
  <dependency>
   <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
   <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
  </dependency>
  <dependency>
   <groupId>org.postgresql</groupId>
   <artifactId>postgresql</artifactId>
   <version>9.4.1208.jre7</version>
  </dependency>
  <dependency>
   <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
   <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
   <scope>test</scope>
  </dependency>
  <dependency>
   <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
   <artifactId>spring-context-support</artifactId>
   <version>4.2.1.RELEASE</version>
  </dependency>
  <dependency>
   <groupId>commons-validator</groupId>
   <artifactId>commons-validator</artifactId>
   <version>1.4.0</version>
  </dependency>
  <dependency>
   <groupId>org.apache.tomcat.embed</groupId>
   <artifactId>tomcat-embed-jasper</artifactId>
   <scope>provided</scope>
  </dependency>


  <!-- Logging-->
  <dependency>
   <groupId>log4j</groupId>
   <artifactId>log4j</artifactId>
   <version>1.2.17</version>
  </dependency>

  </dependencies>
 <repositories>
  <repository>
   <id>spring-snapshots</id>
   <name>Spring Snapshots</name>
   <url>https://repo.spring.io/libs-snapshot</url>
   <snapshots>
    <enabled>true</enabled>
   </snapshots>
  </repository>
 </repositories>

 <build>
  <plugins>
   <plugin>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
   </plugin>
  </plugins>
 </build>
 

</project>
```

Comment: Are you sure this is a minimal (http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) example to reproduce your issue? I'd recommend to try to reduce your code in the question.

Comment: Did you get this to work?

Comment: I don't see where your class MyPostgreSQL94Dialect is used.